# SQL commamd Line

Tags: sql, oracle

How to apply Not null constraint in SQL command line in Oracle database

Comment: An example of what you're trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 0):

this example shows if you want to give a constraint a name

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY (mynumber NUMBER(8,2) CONSTRAINT my_cons_name NOT NULL);
```

this example show if you do not want to give a constraint a name

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
MODIFY (mynumber NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL);
```

source: https://community.oracle.com/thread/45653